# Lodash _.debounce with queue combination?

Tags: javascript, queue, lodash, debouncing

Is there a way to keep all the arguments the debounced function has been called with, keep them in a queue and then fire a single batch action ?

For example:

```
const debounceWithQueue = _.debounce(myFn, 1000);
```

```
debounceWithQueue(1);
debounceWithQueue(2);
debounceWithQueue(3);
```

and after one second has passed I want my function `myFn` to be executed with an argument `[1, 2, 3]`

```
myFn([1, 2, 3]);
```

Also, is it possible to fire if either 1 second has passed *OR* the queue has reached a certain size (keeping count of how many times the debounceWithQueue function has been called

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can wrap `_.debounce()` with a function that holds an array as a queue. The original function (`fn`) is wrapped by `runFn`, which calls the original function with the queue, and clear the queue. We apply debounce to `runFn` (the `debounced` function).

When you use `debounceWithQueue` on a function, a new function is returned. Whenever the new function is called, it queues the current arguments, checks the length of the arguments, and if they are over the maximum, it flushes `debounced`. If the queue is not full, `debounced` is called instead.

**Note**: I collect the arguments using rest params (`...a`), which means that every call to the function, adds an array to `args` array. You can flatten the array of array to a single array of arguments, by changing `fn(args);` to `fn(args.flat());`, but I think that it's better if the original function can handle the array of arrays.

```js
const debounceWithQueue = (fn, wait, { maxSize = Infinity, ...debounceOptions } = {}) => {
  const args = [];
  
  const runFn = () => {
    fn(args);
    
    args.length = 0;
  };
  
  const debounced = _.debounce(runFn, wait, debounceOptions);
  
  const cancel = () => {
    debounced.cancel();
    
    args.length = 0;
  };
  
  const queuedDebounce = (...a) => {
    args.push(a);
  
    if(args.length >= maxSize) debounced.flush() 
    else debounced();
  }
  
  queuedDebounce.cancel = cancel;
  
  queuedDebounce.flush = debounced.flush;
  
  return queuedDebounce;
}

const flatConsole = args => console.log(args.flat())

const fn1 = debounceWithQueue(flatConsole, 1000);
fn1('a');
fn1('b');
fn1('c');
setTimeout(() => fn1('d'), 2000);

const fn2 = debounceWithQueue(flatConsole, 1000, { maxSize: 4 });
fn2(1);
fn2(2);
fn2(3);
fn2(4);
fn2(5);
fn2(6);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```